# pass value from one ons-template to another using angular js [Onsen UI]

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I want some values from one ons-template to another, i have tried sending values from ons-template to controller and getting back to another ons-template from a controller, but is there any way i can get the values directly from one ons-template to another without calling the controller? Below is my code.

sendmoney.html

```
<ons-template id="sendmoney.html">
        <ons-page modifier="shop-details"  class='page_bg'>
            <ons-toolbar style="background-color: #16A500;">
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.openMenu();">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">Send Money</div>
                <div class="right">
                    <ons-toolbar-button onclick="doContactPicker()">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-plus" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
            </ons-toolbar>                                          
            <div ng-controller="getUserContacts">
            <ons-list-header>Select Contact</ons-list-header>
            <ons-list style="margin: -1px 0">   
                <div ng-show="loading" class="loading"><img src="img/loading.gif" height="50px" width="50px"></div>
                <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="list-item" ng-repeat="x in contacts track by $index" style="margin-left: 10px;" ng-click="page.pushPage('sendmoney2.html', {animation: 'slide'});">                    
                    <ons-row>                           
                        <ons-col width="52px" style="padding: 10px 0 0 0;">
                            <img src="img/red.png" height="42px" width="42px"/>
                        </ons-col>
                        <ons-col>
                            <header>
                                <span class="item-title">{{x.name}}</span>                                    
                            </header>
                            <p class="swipe-item-desc">{{x.phone}}</p>
                        </ons-col>                              
                    </ons-row>                      
                </ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
```

I want `{{x.name}}` and `{{x.phone}}` in sendmoney2.html template

sendmoney2.html

```
<ons-template id="sendmoney2.html">
    <ons-page modifier="shop-details"  class='page_bg'>
        <ons-toolbar style="background-color: #16A500;">
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.openMenu();">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Send Money</div>                
        </ons-toolbar>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Angular very well, but in plain JS, you simply set a global variable to get around this.  I think of the app design as just one large web page.  That often helps me solve my problems.  So basically just define these in the top of your script:

```
var vName = '';
var vPhone = '';
```

Then set them in the events, this should work.